# SQL Server trigger not acting as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I have these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test_Table1]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [f_id] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test_Table2_Tbl]
(
    [f_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [text] [varchar](500) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Test_Trigger_Delete]
ON [dbo].[Test_Table2_Tbl] 
AFTER DELETE
AS
    INSERT INTO Test_Table2_Tbl (text)
        (SELECT id FROM deleted)

    UPDATE Test_Table1_Tbl
    SET f_id = NULL
    WHERE f_id IN (SELECT id FROM deleted)
GO
```

The keen observer will realize that 'id' does not exist in 'deleted'.

SQL catches that error in the INSERT, but without the INSERT it will let you add the trigger without any complaints.

Why doesn't it catch that error? (Invalid column name 'id'.)

My second question is, why does the `UPDATE` statement update `EVERY` column to `NULL` when id is not found in deleted?

I'm just very confused and need so clarity on why every record matches that `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The only error in your insert is a logical one. id is perfectly valid in that context because id is a column in Test_Table1_Tbl.

Comment: Using your create table and create trigger ddl I cannot create the trigger. Maybe you have a column named id in Test_Table2_Tbl when the trigger was created? That would explain how you could have the trigger and not the column.

Answer (score 2):

Your error in the `UPDATE` is because the query is treated as a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE Test_Table1_Tbl
    SET f_id = NULL
    WHERE Test_Table1_Tbl.f_id IN (SELECT Test_Table1_Tbl.id FROM deleted d);
```

`id` doesn't resolve in `deleted`, so SQL looks out at the next level.

These are the scoping rules for subqueries.  That is why you should *always* use qualified table names when you have subqueries:

```
UPDATE Test_Table1_Tbl
    SET f_id = NULL
    WHERE Test_Table1_Tbl.f_id IN (SELECT d.id FROM deleted d);
```